# How to get IP address of mounted NAS device from Mac OS command line

Tags: mac-osx, network-attached-storage

OS: Mac OS Sierra version 10.12

There's a Seagate D4 NAS device mounted as external device on Mac OS.

I need to determine the NAS device IP address (preferably from command line). Is there a simple way to do that?

Device /dev/disk3s2) is mounted as NTFS, and 'diskutil info' reports no networking details.

Answer (score 4):

First, Open the terminal window and use ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) tool to find-out all the network attached devices.

Use this Command:

```
arp -a
```

It will show all the device that are attached to your network with IP addresses and MAC addresses.

You just have match the MAC address of you NA, which will be printed on it and look for IP in results that the above command has printed.

**Edit:1**

If you have not found your device means your device is currently unassigned. Please try this.

```
arp -s <IP address> <MAC address>
```

**IP**: Assign any free local IP

**MAC**: Use the MAC address that you have found on your device and please use ':' as separator, as you are using MAC OS. For windows, it  would be '-'.

Comment: Thanks, but the output of "arp -a" command mentions none of MACs of the device (I checked carefully several times, both manually and with grep).